# Trying to catch unbalanced delimiters. I need to show the line number associated with it. Having trouble with that and my test file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read in a file and check for delimiters. I have it setup so it reads one line at a time and then one char at a time for that line. I need to show if the delimiters don't match which line number the error was on but I'm having trouble trying to figure out the most efficient way to do it as I keep doing it wrong and getting errors. I also tried to test a text file and it didn't catch the unbalanced delimiters properly. Please help! I've pasted my relevant code below:

```
bool Delimiters::checkFile()
{

bool validInput = false;    

while (!validInput)
{
    cout << "Please enter the location of the source code file to be analyzed: " << endl;
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << endl;
    inData.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);

    if (inData.is_open())
    {
        char c;
        while(getline(inData, fileContents))
        {
            if (st->isFull())
                cout << "Error! Stack is full!" << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < fileContents.length(); ++i)
            {
                c = fileContents.at(i);
                if(c == '{' || c == '[' || c == '(')
                    st->push(c);
                if(c == '}' || c == ']' || c == ')')
                {
                    if(st->isEmpty())
                    {
                        cout << "Stack is empty. Error in line number " << lineNum << "!" <<endl;
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(matches(st->peak(), c) == false)
                    {
                        cout << "Error #1: in line number " << lineNum << "!" <<endl;
                        cout << "Last delimiter entered: " << st->peak() << ". Expected '"; 
                        cout << Delimiters::pair(st->pop())<< "'."  << "Found: " << c << endl;
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(matches(st->peak(), c) == true)
                    {
                        st->pop();
                        return true;    
                    }
                }
            }
            lineNum++;  
        }   
        if(st->isEmpty())
                return true;
        else
        {
            cout << "Error #2: in line number " << lineNum << "!" << endl;
            cout << "Last delimiter entered: " << (st->peak()) << ". Expected '";
            cout << Delimiters::pair(st->pop()) << "'." << endl;
            return false;
        }               
        validInput = true;      
        inData.close(); 
    }   

    /* Error handling, in case file not found. */
    else 
    //Show error message:
        cout << "Error opening file! Please try again!" << endl;
}
}
bool Delimiters::matches(char a, char b)
{
return((a == '{' && b == '}') || (a == '(' && b == ')') || (a == '[' && b == ']')); 
}

char Delimiters::pair(char a)
{
char match;
if(a == '{')
    match = '}';
if(a == '(')
    match = ')';
if(a == '[')
    match = ']';
return match;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unnecessary `return` statement.

```
if(matches(st->peak(), c) == true)
{
    st->pop();
    return true; // You found a matching character but that isn't
                 // a reason to return. You need to keep parsing the file.
}
```

Change that to:

```
if(matches(st->peak(), c) == true)
{
    st->pop();
}
```

Comment: @Melissa, when you find an answer that solves your problem, accept that answer so others won't need to think about answering the question.

Comment: Oops ok sorry about that! I'm a newbie. :)